# How to interpolate prop into the <router-link>?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js

If I did this `{{ name }}`, I got "campaigns"

I want to render that into my link

```
<router-link :to="'/' + '123' + '/' + item.id"> {{ item.name }}</router-link>
```

I've tried replace '123' with  `{{ name }}`

```
<router-link :to="'/' + {{ name }} + '/' + item.id"> {{ item.name }}</router-link>
```

I kept getting

> Failed to compile.
> ./src/components/Table.vue?vue&type=template&id=783f90ce& (./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js?{"cacheDirectory":"node_modules/.cache/vue-loader","cacheIdentifier":"5c3eaf11-vue-loader-template"}!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/loaders/templateLoader.js??vue-loader-options!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--1-0!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./src/components/Table.vue?vue&type=template&id=783f90ce&)
> Module build failed (from ./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/loaders/templateLoader.js):
> SyntaxError: Unexpected token (1:1767)

./src/components/Table.vue?vue&type=template&id=783f90ce& (./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js?{"cacheDirectory":"node_modules/.cache/vue-loader","cacheIdentifier":"5c3eaf11-vue-loader-template"}!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/loaders/templateLoader.js??vue-loader-options!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--1-0!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./src/components/Table.vue?vue&type=template&id=783f90ce&)
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/loaders/templateLoader.js):
SyntaxError: Unexpected token (1:1767)

Answer (score 0):

Mustache syntax is invalid within html attributes. That is, this is invalid:

```
<router-link
  :to="'/' + '123' + '/' + item.id"
>
  {{ item.name }}
</router-link>
```

What is correct syntax is:

```
<router-link
  :to="`/${item.name}/${item.id}`"
>
  {{ item.name }}
</router-link>
```

Moreover, I would recommend checking out passing properties to the route object within the documentation. This will show you that you can declare variables within the `router` such as `:id`.

I would make another recommendation aside from the above to point out that if this was defined as a computed property of the component, it is easily both viewable in devtools and future debugging (e.g. you probably want to return empty string if the object props are undefined).